# Checking whether a string does not present in hash

Tags: perl

I want to perform a check with the following condition.
If the member of `%ans` is not contained in `%test`, print that value of `%ans`.
But why this didn't print it?

```
use Data::Dumper;
my %ans = ("foo" => 1);
my %test = ("bar" => 1);



foreach my $ansrule ( keys %{$ans}  ) {
    if ( !exists $test{$ansrule} ) {
        print "ANS: $ansrule\n";
    }
}
```

https://eval.in/51453

Comment: I've reverted your question to the original state, as your last edit [does work](https://eval.in/51454).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `keys %{$ans}` is not the same as `keys %ans`, and you should've [used the latter](https://eval.in/51454):
`$ans` and `%ans` are *different* variables.

The `%{$ans}` attempts to dereference a hash ref stored in `$ans` variable - which is, apparently, not defined. Have you added `use strict;` to your code, you'd have seen the warning...

```
Global symbol "$ans" requires explicit package name
```

Comment: I corrected it according to your suggestio with `key %ans` but it still doesn't print.

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
foreach my $ansrule ( keys %ans  )
```

instead of

```
foreach my $ansrule ( keys %$ans  )
```

`use strict; use warnings;` would be helpful in detection of such flaws.